# Display expiry date of licence in list of orders

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and [Commerce Licence](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license).

I need to show in the list of orders in user profile, the expiry date of the purchased license.

I looked at the orders view, but it would seem that it is not possible to make a different view for "Commerce Order" and "Commerce licence".

Is there a solution?

Comment: You could try to add a [relation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1920288) from the order to the licence. If it is available, you will be able to add licence details to the order. (But it might not be implemented.)

Comment: I believed that it was not possible, but further to your message I give it a new try and I reached there, I am going to put the solution, thanks Neograph734

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a relation and it worked! Thanks Neograph734